# why gradient colors and aliasing under Lion are different compare to Snow Leopard?

Tags: objective-c, colors, osx-lion, gradient, antialiasing

Just came across one weird problem. I generate programmatically a gradient inside round cornered square like so:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceAdobeRGB1998);
    CGContextRef mcontext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
size_t capacityBarGradientNumLocations = 11;
CGGradientRef Gradient;

CGFloat capacityBarGradientLocations[11] = { /* skipped */  };

CGFloat capacityBarGradientColors[44] = { /* skipped */  };

Gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (colorSpace, capacityBarGradientColors, capacityBarGradientLocations, capacityBarGradientNumLocations);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(mcontext,Gradient, CGPointMake(0,baroffset), CGPointMake(0,barheight+baroffset), 0);
```

I've just noticed that the same code produces completely different results between Lion and Snow Leopard on the same mac (I have a dual boot) and monitor with the same color profiles. Please take a look at the screenshot:
[image: Weird gradient problem under Lion]

Left part if taken under Lion, the right one - under Snow Leopard. How can I fix my gradient appearance under Lion?

Some extra info regarding the above picture. I've used a black color with variable alpha to generate semi transparent gradient i.e:

```
CGFloat capacityBarGradientColors[44] = 
{   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, .65, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, .35, 
            /* skipped */
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, .35, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, .65,
};
```

I thought maybe there is something wrong with the way i use alpha. Decided to use actual colors with Multiply blending mode and alpha set to 1.0 :

```
CGFloat capacityBarGradientColors[44] = 
{  0x59/255., 0x59/255., 0x59/255., 1.0, 
    0xa6/255., 0xa6/255., 0xa6/255., 1.0, 
            /* skipped */
    0xa6/255., 0xa6/255., 0xa6/255., 1.0, 
    0x59/255., 0x59/255., 0x59/255., 1.0,
};
```

Under Snow Leopard I've got the result I've been looking for. But under Lion I've got completely different picture. take a look at the screenshot:
[image: lion blending mode problem]

Left - Lion, right - Snow Leopard

Here is the code changes I did:

```
Gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (colorSpace, capacityBarGradientColors, capacityBarGradientLocations, capacityBarGradientNumLocations);
CGContextSetBlendMode(mcontext, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(mcontext,Gradient, CGPointMake(0,baroffset), CGPointMake(0,barheight+baroffset), 0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(mcontext, kCGBlendModeNormal);
```

Comment: After a few hours going through the code I've tracked down a problem to a CGContextSetShadowWithColor call earlier in the code on a view where I create my gradients. I've replaced the shadow with a gradient and that resolved the problem. The question still stands though... Why the same code produces different results between Lion and Snow Leopard?

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong so the behavior is undefined. I'd like to see all code in a sample project.

Comment: After careful code examination I've found what the problem is. I use     CGContextSetShadowWithColor call to disable shadowing on my context and instead of passing a NULL value for the color I had an actual color passed. updated the line like so:

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor (mcontext, CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f), 0.0f, NULL);

And that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something to do with the color space behaving differently (gamma?) from one OS version to the other. Do you have the same problem if you use `kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB` or `kCGColorSpaceGenericRGBLinear`?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem if I use kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB or kCGColorSpaceGenericRGBLinear. kCGColorSpaceGenericRGBLinear trows all my colors way off, but the difference between Lion and Snow Leopard stays anyways. I've tried a few other color spaces with the same unfortunate result.